# JS - filter v.s. splice in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

##### Background knowledge

We can mutate an array using `splice` and `filter`. `filter` is not a mutable method, but `splice` is a mutable method. So if we use `splice` to an array, then the original array will be mutated.

##### The problem

Now, we are going to do `forEach` to an array and if a condition matches, we will remove an element using `splice` and `filter`. Let's see:

###### 1. `splice`

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
  
  if (el === 2) {
    arr.splice(el, 1); // remove element 2
  }
});
```

Yeah that's what we expect. That prints `1, 2, 4`. Because in the middle of the loop we mutate the `arr`, the result is broken.

###### 2. `filter`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);

  if (el === 2) {
    arr = arr.filter(el => el !== 2); // remove element 2
  }
});
```

However, as you can see, that prints `1, 2, 3, 4` even if we mutate the `arr` in the middle of the loop!

##### The question

We've mutated two arrays in the middle of the loop in a similar way, but the results are different! What happened?

Why does `splice` affect original array but `filter` not?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but in the slice example you remove the 3 at the 2 iteration, although in filter example you remove the 2 at the 2 iteration. Did you try filtering the 3 instead?

Comment: @A_A The result is same. `filter`'s result is `1,2,3,4` but `splice`'s is `1,2,3`.

Comment: Ok. My guess is that `splice` updates the original array, whereas with `arr = arr.filter` you assign a new value to `arr` but the original array is not modified (and sitll used by `forEach`). But I don't know the specs, so I'll wait for someone else to answer :)

Comment: `arr` references an array; `forEach` is called on the referenced array. Reassigning `arr` doesn't change the referenced array, it just points `arr` at a new array. `arr.forEach` isn't re-evaluated on each iteration (nor would it make sense to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply how [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) are defined. `splice` is meant to modify the array (and return removed values) while `filter` is meant to return a copy of the array with only the matching values

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates over the array in ascending index order. Even though you modify the array during e.g. index 3, next iteration it'll just go to the next index, e.g. 4, unless the end of the array is already reached. Mind that once `.forEach` is called on an array, it'll keep working on that array. You setting `arr` to another value doesn't affect the array nor the state of the `.forEach` call. Similar to a regular function call:

```js
let someVariable = 5;
function test(param) {
    someVariable = 6;
    console.log(param); // still prints 5
}
test(someVariable);
```

After all, JavaScript works by reference (or primitive values), you're not passing a pointer to the `someVariable` variable like you can do in some other languages.

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood. You are right! Reassignment confused me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One point of clarification: in the OP's first example he's actually deleting the third value in the array rather than the second one despite the comment indicating he meant to delete the second element (at least, that is what I think he was going for based on the subsequent example).

One would fix that problem by using the second parameter passed to the forEach callback as follows:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr.forEach((el, index) => {
  console.log(el);
  
  if (el === 2) {
    // actually remove the second element instead of the element at index 2
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

What I find interesting is that even if the semantic error is fixed, the console will still show what the OP mentioned:

```
1
2
4
```

This, despite the resulting value of `arr` being set to `[1, 3, 4]` by the `splice()` call.

What happened?  The MDN has a similar example regarding [modifying an array inside a forEach loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#modifying_the_array_during_iteration).  Basically, the callback one passes to `forEach` is invoked for every index of the list until it reaches the length of the list.  In the second invocation, the underlying logic is pointing to index 1 and the callback deletes that index, moving everything currently following that index forward one index in the array: the value `3` is moved to index 1 and the value `4` is moved to index 2.  Because we've already iterated over index 1, the third invocation will be invoked on index 2 which now contains the value `4`.

The following table is another way to see this:

| Iteration | value of `el` | `arr` value before callback | `arr` value after callback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | `[1, 2, 3, 4]` | `[1, 2, 3, 4]` |
| 2 | 2 | `[1, 2, 3, 4]` | `[1, 3, 4]` |
| 3 | 4 | `[1, 3, 4]` | `[1, 3, 4]` |

Basically, you can think of `Array.prototype.forEach` being defined similarly to the following:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callbackFn, thisArg) {
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
    callbackFn.call(thisArg, this.at(index), index, this)
  }
}
```

---

The difference between the two examples is that in the first one, the OP is using `splice` to modify the object referenced by the variable `arr` "in place" (as noted in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).  In the second example, the OP is changing the variable `arr` to point to a new object; however, because `forEach` is a function, the original object referenced by `arr` will be kept in scope by the `forEach` [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) until the function completes.  This becomes a little easier to see when you add a little more logging to the example using the third parameter passed to the callback (the array against which the callback was executed).

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.forEach((el, index, list) => {
  console.log("el:", el, "list:", list, "arr:", arr);

  if (el === 2) {
    arr = arr.filter(el => el !== 2); // remove element 2
  }
});
```

This modified example will produce the following output:

```
el: 1 list: [1, 2, 3, 4] arr: [1, 2, 3, 4]
el: 2 list: [1, 2, 3, 4] arr: [1, 2, 3, 4]
el: 3 list: [1, 2, 3, 4] arr: [1, 3, 4]
el: 4 list: [1, 2, 3, 4] arr: [1, 3, 4]
```

One can see that the value of `list`, which comes from the `forEach` closure, never changes despite `arr` getting overwritten during the second iteration.